# Trying to decode internationalized url

Tags: python, python-3.x, internationalization

I currently have a list of domains some of which are internationalized.

For example one ends with this `xn--nqv7f.com` but I want it to display like this `机构.com`

I'm tried encoding it to `ascii` and `utf-8` but I can't seem to get the console or my website to print it like this.  I'm using python 3.5

```
'xn--nqv7f.com'.decode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

And when I try this I only get this

```
'xn--nqv7f.com'.encode("idna")
b'xn--nqv7f.com'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to encode then decode

```
'xn--nqv7f.com'.encode("idna").decode('idna')
'机构.com'
```